# Product with different sub qty levels

Tags: magento-1.9, stock

Trying to currently work this out and understand it isn't default magento.

I have a product (Red Shoe) and I need to record the qty of different values of the product for example

Red Shoe is made up of:

2 Red Leather, 3 White Cloth

and another product to have the following:

White Shoe

2 White Leather, 3 White Cloth

So if 1 of each product is ordered it will take stock of 2 Red Leather, 2 White Leather and 6 White Cloth.

I understand magento would do the stock for 1 item per order but is there a way to do the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento does have composite products (bundles and configurables), but does not do what you want out of the box, at least not in a way that would then make sense to the customer.

You're actually getting into "resource planning" territory with this approach, something which Magento does not really do, as that tends to be more of an enterprise-level concern.

If you really want to do this without much work, you could create these items as bundle products, and then customize the bundle product display template to hide composite options which are preset with only one choice (as shown below):

[image: Screenshot of single-option bundle item]

Comment: Thanks, would this be possible if we're using configurable products for sizing as well?

Comment: Sorry, that's the big missing out-of-box feature in Magento catalog construction: no nested complex types. Depending on what you "stock" (e.g. a certain size sole, with everything else fabricated per order), you could provide a dropdown of simple product (each one representing a sole size) as options.